# Обработка изображений cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv, pil, pyautogui

Есть у меня маленький код (это бот, который ищет никнеймы мобов):

```py
import os
import cv2
import pyautogui

from PIL import ImageGrab


def screenGrab():
    box = (330, 180, 1030, 540)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    im.save("111.png")
        
screenGrab()


image = cv2.imread("111.png")
low_cl = (240, 240, 240)
high_cl = (255, 255, 255)
find = cv2.inRange(image, low_cl, high_cl)
moments = cv2.moments(find, 1)
x_moment = moments['m10']
y_moment = moments['m01']
area = moments['m00']
x1 = int(x_moment/area) 
y1 = int(y_moment/area) 


def click_img(x, y):
    pg.click(x, y)

click_img(330+x1, 195+y1)
```

Он выделяет только нужные цвета из диапазона. Работает все правильно, но следующее действие, которое мне требуется - это клик по координатам найденных цветов (со сдвигами).

Это тоже работает правильно до того момента, как под эти параметры не еще мобы (подбегают новые). Если мобов становится больше - `moments` изменяет значения и клики становятся хаотичными.

Что можно придумать с этим? Может, разбивать рабочую область на много частей и чтобы он отдельно цвета на них парсил?

Comment: вы можете править свой вопрос. внесите изменения.

Comment: @strawdog спасибо, внес